# Importing multiple RSS feed into Wordpress and sorting them by date

Tags: rss, feed

I have found the following code to import feeds from multiple feeds and show them in wordpress. But, I want to sort all the combined feeds by date and show only 10. How can I do that?

Thanks

```
<?php
  $feed = fetch_feed(array('http://www.site1.com/feed/', 'http://www.site2.com/feed/'));
foreach($feed->get_items() as $item) {
   echo $item->get_title();
}
?>
```

Comment: Take a look at WP RSS Aggregator

Answer (score 1):

### Checking the arguments

The main problem with your attempt is that you assume the function to take an array of arguments. The point is that this doesn't work. The internals of [`fetch_feed()` <sup>Link to source</sup>](http://queryposts.com/function/fetch_feed/) shows you that is simply is a wrapper for the `SimplePie` class, so you have to throw in one URl after each other. In return you get a fully baked `SimplePie object`.

#### Reworked code

So your code should be something like the following:

```
$feeds[] = fetch_feed( 'http://site-a.example.com/feed/' );
$feeds[] = fetch_feed( 'http://site-b.example.com/feed/' );
foreach( $feeds as $feed )
{
    foreach ( $feed->get_items() as $item )
    {
        echo $item->get_title();
    }
}
```

## The solution

The kool thing with this is, that you can (as your code already shows) then use the classes methods. I'm no expert with `SimplePie` (nor have I even used this class), but from looking at the source, there seems to be a `merge_items()` method. Maybe you can use this one:

```
$simple_pie = new SimplePie;
$feeds[] = fetch_feed( 'http://site-a.example.com/feed/' );
$feeds[] = fetch_feed( 'http://site-b.example.com/feed/' );
$feed_posts = $simple_pie->merge_items( $feeds, 0, 10, 10 );
```

Now `merge_items()` takes four arguments.

- `$urls` - an array of `SimplePie` objects (that's why we fetched the feed in the first place)
- `$start`
- `$end`
- `$limit`

Internally the method calls `get_items()` - the exact same you've done. And both methods call a sort callback method that sorts by date.

Task done.